# Registro php ALERTAS

Tags: php, mvc, registro, alert

Tengo terminado mi registro de usuarios para cada uno de los campos junto con la validacion, excepto que quisiera solo poner un detalle y quisiera saber que me hace falta para que cuando seleccione el boton de registrar me aparezca la alerta en pantalla de campo vacio en este caso ya sea para nombre ,apellido, correo o contraseña,es la unica alerta  que no me muestra en pantalla cuando selecciono registrar, solamente me aparece esa alerta cuando me redirijo a la pagina usuario/save pero quisiera que cuando seleccione el boton registrar me aparezca la alerta segun mi codigo que me hace falta poner ? agradezco mucho cualquier orientacion

```
registro.php

<div id="register" style="margin-left:4%;">

    <h1>Registrar usuarios</h1>
    <form action="<?= base_url ?>usuario/save" method="POST">

    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['register'])  &&  $_SESSION['register'] == 'complete') : ?>
        <strong class="alerta"> Registro completado con exito!</strong>
    <?php elseif (isset($_SESSION['register']) && $_SESSION['register'] != 'complete') : 
        $error = $_SESSION['register'];
        echo $error;
    endif; ?>
    
        <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" required />

        <label for="apellidos">Apellidos</label>
        <input type="text" name="apellidos" placeholder="Apellidos" required />

        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" required />

        <label for="password">Contraseña</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña" required />

        <input type="submit" value="Registrarse" required />
        
    </form>

<?php Utils::deleteSession('register')?>
</div>
```

```
Utils.php

<?php
 
class Utils{

    public static function deleteSession($name){
        if(isset($_SESSION[$name])){
           $_SESSION[$name] = null;
           unset($_SESSION[$name]);
        }

        return $name;
    }

/*===============================
   Validacion campos de registro 
 ================================*/

 
            public static function validate($nombre, $apellidos, $email, $password){
                $error = true;
        
                // Validar nombre
                if(empty($nombre)){
                    $error = "<strong class='alerta-error'>Por favor introduzca su Nombre</strong>";
                    return $error;
                }elseif(is_numeric($nombre) && preg_match("/[0-9]/", $nombre)){
                    $error = "<strong class='alerta-error'>Por favor introduzca un Nombre válido</strong>";
                    return $error;
                }else{
                    $error = false; 
                }
        
                // Validar apellido
                if(empty($apellidos)){
                    $error = "Por favor introduzca su <strong>Email</strong>";
                    return $error;
                }elseif(is_numeric($apellidos) && preg_match("/[0-9]/", $apellidos)){
                    $error = "<strong class='alerta-error'>Por favor introduzca un Apellido válido</strong>";
                    return $error;
                }else{
                    $error = false; 
                }
        
                // Validar email
                // Validar que no sea un usuario ya registrado con el mismo email
                $sql = "SELECT email FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email' ";
                $conexion = Database::connect();
                $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($conexion->query($sql));
        
                if(substr_count($email, "@") != 1){
                    $error = "<strong class='alerta-error'>El correo no es válido, falta el signo '@'</strong>";
                    return $error;
                }elseif(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
                    $error = "<strong class='alerta-error'>Por favor introduzca un Email válido</strong>";
                    return $error;
                }elseif(!empty($result)){
                    $error = "<strong class='alerta-error'>El email ya está registrado</strong>";
                    return $error;
                }else{
                    $error = false; 
                }

                // Validar password
                if(empty($password)){
                    $error = "<strong class='alerta-error'>Por favor introduzca su Contraseña</strong>";
                    return $error;
                }elseif(strlen($password) <= 8  &&  preg_match_all('$S*(?=S{8,})S*$', $password) == true){
                    $error = "<strong class='alerta-error'>Introduzca una contraseña de minimo 8 caracteres y contenga simbolos </strong>";
                    return $error;
                }else{
                    $error = false; 
                }
        
                // Devolver el $error
                return $error;
            }


}
?>
```

```
 UsuarioController.php

<?php
require_once 'models/usuario.php';

class usuarioController{ 

    public function index() {
        echo "Controlador Usuarios, Accion index";
    }

    public function registro() {
        require_once 'views/usuario/registro.php';
    }
    
    public function save(){
        if(isset($_POST)){

            $nombre = isset($_POST['nombre']) ? $_POST['nombre'] : false;
            $apellidos = isset($_POST['apellidos']) ? $_POST['apellidos'] : false;
            $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : false;
            $password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : false;

            $validar = Utils::validate($nombre, $apellidos, $email, $password);
          
            if($validar == false){
                $usuario = new Usuario();
                $usuario->setNombre($nombre);
                $usuario->setApellidos($apellidos);
                $usuario->setEmail($email);
                $usuario->setPassword($password);
                $save = $usuario->save();

                if ($save) {
                    $_SESSION['register'] = "complete";
                } else {
                    $_SESSION['register'] = "failed";
                }
            }else{
                $_SESSION['register'] = $validar;
            }
        }else{
            $_SESSION['register'] = "<strong class='alerta-error'>Ha habido un error</strong>";
        }    
        
        header("Location:".base_url.'usuario/registro');
        ob_end_flush();
        }
}


?>

'''
UsuarioModel.php

<?php

class Usuario{
    private $id;
    private $nombre;
    private $apellidos;
    private $email;
    private $password;
    private $rol;
    private $imagen;
    private $db;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = Database::connect();
    }


    function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    function getNombre()
    {
        return $this->nombre;
    }

    function geTApellidos()
    {
        return  $this->apellidos;
    }

    function getEmail()
    {
        return  $this->email;
    }
    
    function getPassword()
    {
        return password_hash($this->db->real_escape_string($this->password), PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => 4]);
    }

    function getRol()
    {
        return  $this->rol;
    }

    function getImagen()
    {
        return  $this->imagen;
    }

    function setid($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    function setNombre($nombre)
    {
        $this->nombre = $this->db->real_escape_string($nombre);
    }

    function setApellidos($apellidos)
    {
        $this->apellidos = $this->db->real_escape_string($apellidos);
    }

    function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $this->db->real_escape_string($email);
    }

    function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    function setRol($rol)
    {
        $this->rol = $rol;
    }

    function setImagen($imagen)
    {
        $this->imagen = $imagen;
    }


    public function save(){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES(NULL, '{$this->getNombre()}', '{$this->getApellidos()}', '{$this->getEmail()}', '{$this->getPassword()}', 'user', null);";
        $save = $this->db->query($sql);
        
        $result = false;
        if ($save){
            $result = true;
        }
        return $result;
    }


}

?>
'''
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que para pasar los datos desde el cliente (HTML) al servidor (PHP) uses Ajax o la nueva API Fetch, y que controles en primer lugar en el cliente, por ejemplo, dejando el botón `Enviar` desactivado hasta que todos los campos requeridos del formulario no estén llenos. Luego, en el servidor, puedes usar [filtros de validación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/filter.filters.validate.php)  (para datos como email) y [filtros de saneamiento](https://www.php.net/manual/es/filter.filters.sanitize.php) para otros tipos de datos, y controlar el código según el resultado de esas validaciones.

Comment: solamente quiero saber que me hace falta para que salga la alerta en pantalla cuando selecciono el boton registrar, como tal no me pidieron que lo dejara desabilitado y no me esta permitido usar algun framework para esto , todo es MVC, como dije anteriormente la alerta solo me sale cuando coloca la url usuario/save pero no cuando selecciono el boton

Comment: ¿Puedes indicar exactamente en qué parte del código es el problema?

Comment: en la parte del submit quiero que al seleccionar el boton me vote la alerta de campo vacio no se si no soy claro

Comment: Tendrías que hacer lo mismo que haces en `save`, recoger los datos y mandarlos a validar: `$validar = Utils::validate($nombre, $apellidos, $email, $password);`

Comment: un ejemplo por favor, tendria que colocarlo en registro?

Comment: Puedes pensar en reutilizar código, por ejemplo, si `save`  y `registro` pueden llamarse aparte, tendrías que poner la recogida de datos que haces en `save` en otro método y usar ese método para recoger los datos tanto en `save` como en `registro`

Comment: no hay una manera de que me imprima en cada campo la alerta , de manera mas simple sin hacer tanto codigo ? porque si ya tengo  las validaciones para que voy a crear otro metodo

Comment: Claro que sí puedes, precisamente por eso dije en mi comentario anterior: *si `save` y `registro` pueden llamarse **aparte*** tienes que centralizar la validación de los datos en un solo método, porque de lo contrario tendrías que repetir lo mismo que haces en `save` en `registro` para validar. La cuestión sería, ¿por qué tienes un método `save` y otro método `registro`? ¿No es eso lo que tienes que resolver? ¿En algunos contextos llamas a `save` y en otros a `registro`? ¿No puedes llamar **a un mismo método** en todos los contextos?

Comment: creo que no me estas entendiendo yo no me refiero a eso, solo quiero que tambien imprima las alertas ya definidas en cada uno de los campos

Comment: Para que te imprima las alertas en cada uno de los campos, tú tendrías que: 1. Verificar en el servidor qué campos no han sido llenados; 2. Devolver una respuesta con esos campos y actualizar su estado, con un mensaje indicativo de que el campo tal no ha sido llenado o bien, redibujar el formulario ... Esto es tedioso del modo en que intentas hacerlo. Es importante comprender que cuando envías un formulario lo que ocurre es que la página se recarga, mandando al servidor los datos y reflejar la respuesta del servidor supondría de nuevo repintar los elementos ...

Comment: El tipo de validación que tú quieres (que se ponga un indicador de campo no rellenado) se suele hacer en Javascript (del lado del cliente) porque ahí puedes verificar el estado de los elementos sin tener que ir al servidor (enviando el formulario). En ese sentido iba mi primer comentario en tu pregunta, pero tú descartaste esa posibilidad de plano. Pues hacer este tipo de cosas desde el servidor será harto tedioso y totalmente contrario a la práctica habitual en este tipo de casos.